# How to hide the toggle menu by clicking and taking me to the beginning of the section, not 20px below the beginning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I add the code below the menu even closes when I click, but it doesn't take me to the starting point of the section. It takes me a little below, unlike what happens in my original code without adding the script below.

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
$('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

});

MY ORIGINAL CODE: https://www.codeply.com/go/gD2F6iVFm0

CODE WITH PROBLEM: https://www.codeply.com/go/eIKdPVCBih

Could someone show me where I'm going wrong? How do I when the toggle menu closes open the start of the clicked section as it happens without this code that closes the menu on click.

Comment: `it doesn't take me to the starting point of the section.` What does that mean? I added your code and it works.

Comment: May be you have no idea about this menu. Remove this $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  var target = $(this.hash)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top-60
  }, 900)
}) there will not be toggle.

Comment: When you add the code I mentioned above, it takes about 20px below the beginning of the section when I click on the toggle menu (for mobiles), it would take me to the section name, but it takes me below that title, where I already we have the section text. I put the code for you to click on the toggle menu and see that it does not take me to the beginning of the section (title) but below that: https://www.codeply.com/go/eIKdPVCBih

Comment: By removing this part of the code I lose the smooth scrolling effect and it takes me below the section title because it has no 60px offset, Mr. Perfectionist. I would love to use this feature and make my site even more fantastic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the toggle menu close on click and get me to the beginning of the section correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683485/how-to-make-the-toggle-menu-close-on-click-and-get-me-to-the-beginning-of-the-se)