# How to make the toggle menu close on click and get me to the beginning of the section correctly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I add the code below, the menu even closes when I click, but that doesn't get me to the starting point of the section. This takes me a few pixels down, unlike in my original code without adding the script.

script in question:

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Could someone show me where I'm going wrong? How do I close the toggle menu in mobile by correctly clicking and descending to the beginning of the section and not a few pixels down. The correct behavior happens without this code that closes the menu on click, but would like to have a menu that closes automatically on click. Does anyone give a light?

MY ORIGINAL CODE WORKING: https://www.codeply.com/go/gD2F6iVFm0

PROBLEM CODE: https://www.codeply.com/go/eIKdPVCBih

Gif with the problem below - at the end of the click, I show where it takes me and then climb to the place I would like it to take me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqVYn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have ran the code you have provided on Chrome 76 on MacOS, but I could not reproduce the issue. On both examples, upon adding the following snippet the website appears to be working correctly.

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Are you sure the problem does not lie in the browser rendering the website differently or mistreating the script? Could you provide more details on your test environment?

Comment: I use Chrome 76 on Windows 10. I believe the easiest way to show you the problem is through this gif: https://imgur.com/a/S2FZwJL#Sa3boQF

On mobile, when I click on a menu item it takes me a few pixels below the beginning of the section, I would like it to take me before the title of this section, as it works in the desktop version. Without adding the mentioned code works correctly, however, the toggle menu does not close automatically on click.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to closing the menu.

The issue is that the height of the navbar is different depending on the screen width. You have an offset of 60 pixels hardcoded into your scroll script. This works fine when the screen is desktop width, but it's not quite right on smaller screens.

To make sure it's always accurate, you can get the height of the navbar right before scrolling.

Here's an updated version of your scroll script:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  var offset = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset
  }, 900)
});
```

The `offset` variables replaces `60` and gets the height using [.outerHeight()](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to make sure it's always accurate.